# how to test netty memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, netty

I add `-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=ADVANCED` for leak detecting on production.
And there are some logs:

> ERROR io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
>   WARNING: 4 leak records were discarded because the leak record count is limited to 4. Use system property io.netty.leakDetection.maxRecords to increase the limit.
>   Recent access records: 5

Does it means it must will happen memory leak?

I want to test it on local environment, so I set `-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=PARANOID`, but there are no the above memory leak records logs.

Answer (score 1):

To detect leak on my development environment, I have reduce the heap size to 12 MB with this vm argument: `-mx12m`

Now with this, Netty is able to detect some leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The log means that you have a memory-leak, so yes there is a leak. You can either configure leak detection via the system property (as you did) or via `ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel(...)`.

That you are not able to see the leak on your local machine may mean that you not see the same "allocation" patterns as on the prod server.

Comment: inboundChannel channelRead if it does not pass it onto next handler, it should call ReferenceCountUtil.release. However the official example https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/helloworld/HttpHelloWorldServerHandler.java does not have leak problem, why?

Comment: Actually I think it has a leak if the request contains a body. Let me fix it.