# java heap memory management insufficient memory

Tags: java, netty

When a netty async server-and-client project is running on linux, it runs out all available memories, like this:
[image: linux console]

So I run it on windows, and JMC show heap like this:

[image: JMC memory]

My questions are: why windows and linux behaves differently, is there somewhere I could configure linux jvm to have a heap memory release? And why there is a heap release in windows (GC)? How to find out suspicious piece of code that takes up so much memory?

**EDIT**: linux is 4G, windows is 8G, but I don't think the absolute value causes the running result differences. Project does not directly handle raw bytebuff, it uses `HttpServerCodec` and `HttpObjectAggregator` for bytebuf. The command to run in linux is `java -jar xx.jar`. I would like to know not only **why difference, why sawtooth** but also **how to locate the one that takes up so much memory**. JMC shows another figure, and I don't know why a thread can have such a high block number. netty threads IO have a 99LINE 71ms. 
[image: JMC threads]

**UPDATED:**
Now I would like to **locate which part of the code takes up so much memory**. JMC heap shows EDEN SPACE is very high, and I bing it and found out EDEN SPACE is for `new` object. Originally, the project used spring-boot which has tomcat servlet 3.0 as container and a apache httpclient pool for client, now only these parts has been changed by using netty asynchronous server and netty asynchronous client, while other parts are remained (still use spring for bean management). Netty server and client handlers are shared for all requests (handlers are singleton spring beans). With such small changes, I don't believe the amount of `new` objects are significantly increased that it ends in 1.35G memory [image: JMC heap]

**UPDATE**After running netty and springboot projects separately, I get more statistical data:

1. OS memory 8G. springboot edition project: PS Old Generation: capacity=195MB; used=47MB; 24% used. And it has 692,971 objects with a total size 41,848,384.
2. OS memory 16G. netty version project: PS Old Generation: capacity = 488MB; used 327MB; 67% used. It has 1,243,432 objects with a total size 221,427,824.

netty version: heap dump shows it has a 279,255 instances of class `io.netty.buffer.PoolSubpage` compared to the 2nd most 7,222 instances of class `org.springframework.core.MethodClassKey`. Both versions have service (our own class) objects limited, no more than 3000.

I have tried to run with `-Xmx1024m` on 4G memory linux, still causes the same out of memory problem.

Comment: How much memory do the Windows and Linux machines have?

Comment: You might have some bugs in the way you are using netty byte buffers.
You can try enabling the netty memory leak logging.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676085/how-to-test-netty-memory-leak

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information in order to be able to get an answer to this. Are you running the Windows and Linux tests on the same machine? What is the configuration of the machine(s) in terms of memory? You've posted a JMC trace for Windows but not Linux. The error you are seeing is the Linux kernel not being able to allocate memory to the JVM. What parameters are you setting on the java command line?

Comment: This is most likely a memory tuning problem.  This error occurs when there is not enough native memory to continue operating.  I suggest you ensure you have enough free swap space and this shouldn't happen.

Comment: @StephenC windows 8G, linux 4G. But the absolute value is not important I think, figure shows it seems like a "garbage bin" dumping every time it thinks it is full.

Comment: @Magnus I don't manipulate netty bytebuff directly, it is mostly http.

Comment: @Speakjava I updated the post.

Comment: So how much was Eden Max when using Tomcat? Are you claiming that it was a lot smaller, or do you think 1.35G is too much? If you think 1.35G is too much, what are you basing that on?

Comment: @Kayaman I just compared the project when it is netty or springboot separately. Because Eden space is mostly affected by GC (multiple snapshots give different results), so we focused on the other main difference: old gen. The experiments are added in UPDATE section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing on Windows is normal GC behaviour.  The application is generating garbage, and then you hit a threshold that causes the GC to run.  The GC frees a lot of heap.  And then the application starts again.   The result is a sawtooth pattern in the heap occupancy.

This is normal.   Every JVM behaves more or less like this.

---

The behavior on Linux looks like something is trying to allocate something large (77MB) in native memory, and failing because the OS is refusing to give the JVM that much memory.   Typically that happens because the OS has run out of resources; e.g. physical RAM, swap space, etc.

> Windows 8G, linux 4G.

That probably explains it.  Your Linux system has only half the physical memory of the Windows system.   If you are running netty with a large Java heap AND your Linux OS has not been configured with any swap space, then it is plausible that the JVM is using all of the available virtual memory.  It could even be happening at JVM startup.

(If we assume that the max heap size has been set the same for both Windows and Linux, then on Windows there is at least 4.5GB of virtual address space available for other things.  On Linux, only 0.5GB.  And that 0.5GB has to hold all of the non-heap JVM utilization ... plus the OS and various other user-space processes.   It is easy to see how you could have used all of that ... leading to the allocation failure.)

If my theory is correct, then the solution would be to change the JVM command line options to make -Xmx smaller.

(Or increase the available physical / virtual memory.   But be careful with increasing the virtual memory by adding swap space.  If the virtual/physical ratio is too large you can get virtual memory "thrashing" which can lead to terrible performance.)

Comment: the JMC figure I updated has netty receiver threads block number 160,000 level, and is accumulating. Do you thinks this deserves attention?

Comment: I don't know what that number means.  If that is the number of worker threads, then that could part of your problem.  Each thread uses a large chunk of off-heap memory for its stack.  You certainly don't need 160,000 threads.  Probably 200 is plenty.

Comment: JMC daemon live thread count is less than 80, so I guess that is not the the number of threads. Instead, I think it is the number  when this thread is blocked. So that thread was blocked 160,000 times.

Comment: In that case it is most likely irrelevant.

Comment: I have tried -Xmx1024m, the same error. please see updates.

Comment: OK ... so my original theory is probably wrong.  It looks like a memory leak of some kind.

Comment: yes, I guess netty `bytebuf` causes a memory leak, I'll open another question for this if I need more help on this specific topic.