# Netty memory leak for http server. When to release message?

Tags: java, netty

Unless using `SimpleChannelInboundHandler channelRead0`, one should release input packets if `ctx.fireChannelRead` is not called.

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    log.error("receive {}", msg);
    if (msg instanceof FullHttpRequest) {            
        FullHttpRequest req = (FullHttpRequest) msg;
        ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
        clientChannel.writeAndFlush(new RequestWrapper(req, foo)); 
    }
}
```

`clientChannel.writeAndFlush` when success, push `requestWrapper` into a queue. netty does not show `LEAK warnings`, but as described in [jvm out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148274/java-heap-memory-management-insufficient-memory), the Old Gen of this project increases, event with  `ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg)`.

1. if http input message is not released, why [official example](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/helloworld/HttpHelloWorldServerHandler.java) does not call release explicitly?
2. in `channelRead`, if received msg is set in another bean, and then this bean is passed on by `ctx.fireChannelRead`, should I call release for this msg, like code above?
3. if a new object is passed on by `ctx.fireChannelRead(newObject)`, should I call `release(newObject)` in the next handler?

like this:

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    ctx.fireChannelRead("hello world");
}

public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    assert "hello world".equals(msg);
    ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg); // is this necessary if it is created in the former handler?
}
```

4. How about write operation, should I also call release for write object?

like this:

```
@Override
public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {
    ctx.write("bye", promise);
}

@Override
public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {
    assert "bye".equals(msg);
    // should I call ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg); ?
    ctx.write(“bye bye”, promise);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Maybe it's a bug.Honestly,I don't know.But it must release the obj if you do not call **ctx.fireChannelRead()** in your Handler(interrupt the handlers' chain). Or the **TailContext** will release the obj.

2.You can't release the msg in this Handler,if you do,maybe other context will allocate the obj that used in this context.You should release the object only if the bean is end;

3.Your new object is not implement **ReferenceCounted**,so why you need to release the object?Just return false but do nothing in **ReferenceCountUtil** as follow:

```
    public static boolean release(Object msg) {
    if (msg instanceof ReferenceCounted) {
        return ((ReferenceCounted) msg).release();
    }
    return false;
}
```

4.You are not necessary need to release the **write object** because netty will release after send the object

Comment: I did several experiments, and I agree with the first 3. About the last one, I'll open an answer to illustrate it.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of experiments and debugged into the source code, about the 4th point:
`ReferenceCountUtil.refCnt`:

```
public static int refCnt(Object msg) {
    return msg instanceof ReferenceCounted ? ((ReferenceCounted) msg).refCnt() : -1;
}
```

because every netty handler is a responsible chain pattern, `write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise)` can actually have any object msg (argument delivered along the chain). It only needs to manually call release in this situation:

```
@Override
public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {
    FullHttpResponse fullHttpResponse = ...
    ctx.write(fullHttpResponse, promise);
}
```

The instantiation of `FullHttpResponse` finally calls `ByteBuffer.allocate` which comes with a refCnt plus 1.

If in the following handlers, due to exceptions or `userFiredEvents`, this `FullHttpResponse` is not sent out by calling:

```
    ctx.write(msg, promise);
    ctx.flush();
```

then `FullHttpResponse` needs to be manually released. The last but not the least, if a `FullHttpResponse` has refCnt  released, it does not send out. From the point of client, request hangs.